# How can I see a summary of diffrences when updating working copy to specific revision in SVN

Tags: svn, diff, revision

I would like to do a SVN update between a working copy and a specific revision.

Something like:
svn update (project_directory) -r (revision_number)

How can I get a summery of changes (files added, removed, conflicts, etc.) before doing the update?

I tried:
svn diff - but --summarize option only works between two repositories
svn status - only works between working copy and Head

Any idea?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a range for the diff command. See the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) Chapter for diff. Use:

```
svn diff -r 300:HEAD
```

Would give you a diff between rev 300 and the current HEAD revision.

```
svn diff -r 300
```

Would give you a diff between rev 300 and your working copy

Comment: I need diff between my working copy and a specific revision.
Not specific revision and the head.

Comment: Then use `svn diff -r 300`. That would compare your working copy with rev 300

Comment: Great, closer :)
And how do I get it as summary (per file change)
Thanks!

Comment: Summarizing diff can only compare repository to repository

Comment: This is per file change. you basically get a `.patch` file for that. You can use a diff tool to load it up, like `meld`, that would show you stuff per file, highlighted and graphical.

Comment: Write a script that will generate you per file change. You work on Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Server- linux
Laptop- windows

The diff file is a good solution, but I would want a per file one-line summery (if that's possible).